# What is a good way to maintain/pass state across in "Chain of Responsibility" pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

For any chaining implementation for puposes like piping (similar to Java servlet filter chain), if I need to, how do I pass context between filters?/steps?

Also, does it violate the design principle because now I am introducing states and coupling the chain steps using states. (One chain step depends on another step that introduces an attribute)

Should I be considering some other pattern to do the needful?

Comment: There's always setAttribute: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) could help too

Comment: Thanks. Just updated the question to know if the design makes sense